# Why does this BST implementation not work?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, implementation

As part of a project I have to implement a BST with the purpose of sorting through a big dictionary of keys and values. However, I'm having some problems with my code. Specifically, I get an error message because I've exceeded the maximum recursion limit.

Here is the code:

```
@dataclass
class Node:
    key: Any = None
    value: Any = None
    left: Any = None
    right: Any = None

def put(self, key, value):
    new_node = Node(key, value)
    if new_node.value < self.value:
        if self.left is None:
            self.left = Node(key, value, None, None)
        else:
            self.put(key, value)
    elif new_node.value > self.value:
        if self.right is None:
            self.right = Node(key, value, None, None)
        else:
            self.put(key, value)
```

I understand I've created an infinite recursive function, but I dont understand why. Looking at it, it seems to me that it should not be infinite. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Think about what happens when you try to put something to a node with both left and right children. Namely - Is there anything different about recursive call that might cause different result?

Comment: Looking at the code I wanna say that if a node has 2 children it should determine if it is smaller or larger than those children and thus re-enter the function and do the same thing for the next child until it finds a free spot to attach itself too. But from your answer I garner that that isn't what is happening. Could you elaborate a little bit further?

Comment: It should reenter the function for a child - but are you reffering to the child when calling? You are calling `put` back on the same object.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Would changing "self.put" --> "self.left/right.put" (depending on the size of new_node.value) make it enter the child? Looking at it, it seems like it would work but I'm still new to programming so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your recursive calls **self.put(key, value)** are identical (same arguments) to the initial call, which causes the infinite loop; think about how you want your algorithm to behave (simulating the process on a diagram helps).

For future reference, here's the fixed code (only fixes the issue mentioned in the questions; there's still room for improvements).

```
@dataclass
class Node:
    key: Any = None
    value: Any = None
    left: Any = None
    right: Any = None

def put(self, key, value):
    new_node = Node(key, value)
    if new_node.value < self.value:
        if self.left is None:
            self.left = Node(key, value, None, None)
        else:
            self.left.put(key, value)
    elif new_node.value > self.value:
        if self.right is None:
            self.right = Node(key, value, None, None)
        else:
            self.right.put(key, value)
```

Comment: Would changing self.put(key, value) to self.left/right.put(key, value) solve the issue?

Comment: Indeed, you put your finger on it :) You might want (perhaps later) to add provisions too for the case the user tries to enter a value already in your BST.

Comment: @Swifty You might want to edit your question to include the solution OP reached, as your question is accepted and future users might want to come across your answer.